# How to make particle hair face same direction on a branch? (Like pine branch)

Tags: particles, hair

I created a branch with needles on it. I used Particles to create needles. Currently my branch looks like this:

[image]

All the needles facing in the direction of a normals.

I want to make needles like this:

[image]

So they face the direction the branch is facing.

I have tryed changing the Velocity/Rotation setting in the particle settings, but i have not been able to get the result i want.

This is the "best" result i could get by playing with "Tangent" setting in the "Velocity" menu.

[image]

As you can see the result is total mess. Needles on tope of a mesh are facing the right direction, but needles on the bottom facing the complete opposite direction.

Please share you thoughts. Is it possible to do what i want at all using the hair system?

Answer (score 0):

The *Hair Velocity Tangent* is based on *UV direction*.

I've taken a plane and applied a simple *Particle System*.

[image]

If I go to the *UV Editor* and rotate the plane's face like so (roughly -150 degrees):

[image]

The hair grows in a different direction.

[image]

For a more complex object it's a matter of making sure all of the UV faces are oriented in the proper direction, either manually or by finding the correct unwrap method.