# particle system object orientation

Tags: particles

I want to scatter leaves on terrain using a particle system.  The leaf-object is a plane whose surface is parallel with the terrain.  My assumption was that the scattered leaves would therefore "lay flat" on the terrain.  But they don't, rather they are turned 90 degrees on edge, i.e. standing vertical.  They are half-above and half-below the terrain, which is consistent with origin at center of plane.  I've tried rotating the source object X, Y and Z each by 90%, but that doesn't solve it.

Note that origin of source object is centered on the plane, but slightly below in z-axis to allow for small rotation from the "normal" emission axis.

[image: view from above terrain]

[image: view from under terrain]

[image: source object]

Comment: have you tried to rotate the particle object in Edit mode?

Comment: I have not tried rotating in edit mode; only object mode.  Is that my issue?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214225/110840 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/241663/110840

Comment: Yes, rotating the mesh in edit mode solved the issue.  I feel dumb for this rookie error.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate your particle object in *Edit* mode or enable its *Object Rotation* option if you want the particle system to take into account the object rotation in *Object* mode:

[image]